# Matlab - Inserting an element in a set

Tags: matlab, output

I'm planning to do the following in `matlab`:

- Create an empty set
- Insert an element which specifies a certain criterion in it

So, as a quick run on the matlab command line I did the following:

```
>> e=78

e =

    78

>> Ck=[]

Ck =

     []

>> Cn=Ck+e

Cn =

     []
```

But, I was expecting to get the following:

```
Cn = [78]
```

Why didn't I get the expected result? And, how can I solve this out?

Thanks.

Comment: could not you initialize Ck as `0` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@plus` operator is defined as an arithmetic operation, but not as a set operation.

To add to an existing (1D) set at specified locations, you perform catenation and/or indexing. For example, to add at the end of a set, you can write

```
Cn = [Ck,e];
```

or

```
Cn = Ck;
Cn(end+1) = e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'll be wrong, but I would initialize an empty array by means of `zeros`, like:

```
C = zeros(m,n)
with m,n = 1,2,...,N
```

Then, you input your second array/matrix and treat it according to whichever algorithm you have in mind.

I hope this helps.